# While Loop as a Cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, cursor

My case is a typical study case which can be solved by cursor construction easily but my question is why my statement is only correct in below-mentioned situation? The more brakes are the statement works worse. Maybe, the temporary table I use is totally unneeded? Definately, there are logical mistakes in my concept.

Generally I have a table MJ_IDT where:

1. `identity_col` is datatype `int identity(1,1)`
2. `data_col` is datatype `int`, it allows null values

   identity_col  data_col
   1             AAAAA
   2             CCCCC
   3             BBBBB
   5             ddddd

I would like to prepare a while loop which its task is to find all brakes and fill it with a proper value, in this case will be a pair 4 NULL.

I additionaly create a temporary table #mj_id, which is used in my sql statement as follows.

```
id  id_col
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   5
```

My sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE #mj_id
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    id_col int NULL
)

INSERT INTO #mj_id (id_col)
SELECT identity_col FROM MJ_IDT

DECLARE 
    @counter_next   int = 1,
    @incremental    int = 1,
    @counter_prev   int = 0;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1 FROM #mj_id 
              WHERE id = @counter_next) 
  AND @counter_next < (SELECT MAX(identity_col) FROM MJ_IDT)
BEGIN   
    IF (SELECT id_col FROM #mj_id 
        WHERE id = @counter_next) - @counter_prev > @incremental
    BEGIN
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT MJ_IDT ON;

        INSERT INTO MJ_IDT (identity_col)
        VALUES (@counter_next);

        SET @counter_prev = (SELECT id_col FROM #mj_id 
                             WHERE id = @counter_next);
        SET @counter_next = @counter_next + @incremental;

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT MJ_IDT OFF;
    END
    ELSE
       SET @counter_prev = (SELECT id_col FROM #mj_id 
                            WHERE id = @counter_next);
       SET @counter_next = @counter_next + @incremental;
    END
```

It works in this case, but when my table MJ_IDT is:

```
1   AAAAA
2   CCCCC
3   BBBBB
5   ddddd
6   ggggg
8   ggggg
```

It is not working. Could you help me fill brakes in identity columns?

Comment: How can `data_col` be `int` if the values are all character strings?

Comment: What is your expected output? I dont think you require a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Important note to be aware of:

From your question it sounds like you are trying to identify and rectify gaps within the automatically generated `identity` values.  This is a pointless endeavour as the `identity` values are not guaranteed to be sequential, just unique.

---

## Actual answer to your question:

You do not need a cursor or loop for this, just a table of numbers to `join` to that will fill in the gaps for you.  You can build one of these using a tally table:

```
declare @MJ_IDT table (identity_col int, data_col nvarchar(10));
insert into @MJ_IDT values(1,'AAAAA'),(2,'CCCCC'),(3,'BBBBB'),(5,'ddddd');

              -- Create table with 10 rows in it:
with t(t) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
              -- Cross join this table to exponentially increase the number of rows,
              -- then return the row_number of enough rows to cover up to your max ID:
    ,n(n) as (select top (select max(identity_col) from @MJ_IDT) row_number() over (order by (select null))
              from t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6
             )
select n.n as identity_col
        ,m.data_col
from n
    left join @MJ_IDT m
        on(n.n = m.identity_col)
order by n.n;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+----------+
| identity_col | data_col |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 | AAAAA    |
|            2 | CCCCC    |
|            3 | BBBBB    |
|            4 | NULL     |
|            5 | ddddd    |
+--------------+----------+
```